# How to update a list item status automatically using NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

For instance, in App Store when there's 2 different tabs of apps and some application appears in both tabs, when I click to download it in one, the app status in the other one is automatically updated. Is there a way to do so using NSNotificationCenter in iOS? Images below
[image: Tab window]

So after I select the Gmail app for instance...[image: Gmail selected]

And then when I go back to the list of apps, its no longer asking me to obtain the app, it's already updated[image: status updated]

How is that possible?

Comment: This is too broad of a topic, in general how to implement the model layer in your app. [1] You can share instance objects between screens, so if the state of one object changes, it also shows on the other screen [2] if you use core data, the fetched managed objects are reused automatically [3] you can send a NSNotification when you save your objects and catch the notification on the other screen and refresh. Again, too many options.

Comment: @Alistra can you write this as an answer so I can select as best one? It really helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Grigor Hakobyan comments, I started digging into the web and maybe he is correct.

I would tell you to read this article.
https://davidnix.io/post/stop-using-nsnotificationcenter/

It's looks like the NSNotificationCenter isn't a really good option, and you can use the Delegate Pattern to this case, which looks like a better option

Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

Using **NSNotificationCenter** is a very bad solution, just reload your tableView(collectionView) when user select any tab and use advanced OOP principles

Comment: I checked the app store and it doesn't looks like is reloading. Can you say anything else to understand better why NotificationCenter isn't a good solution? Should I reload the uiviewcontroller without firing the search again?

Comment: Ok, my english is bad (probably worse then yours), so no problems. Let's try to understand the steps. When I open the top charts at the first time, it will load for sure. Ok. But when I go to the search apps and type "Gmail", I can see the app there. Both places shows the app with the same state. Now, if you click to install the app at search, the app will update the state in the chart tab (without a reloading). How do we update the property (IsDownloading to true) when set it in another tab? The notification looks good to me, don't?

Comment: Each app has unique id , you can cache all created app instance downloaded status on simple dictionary which key is app id and value is app downloaded status, so when searching any app and creating new instance just check if cached downloaded status exist , assign it to new instance. Sorry for bad English :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a segmented control like in the examples you showed, you should have a function that calls whenever you select a segment. In that function you can either reload the data or the tableviews.

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```